# Mapping generic parameter to compile time data in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, sequelize.js

I'm playing around with trying to disentangle a codebase from Sequelize. Right now we have tons of code like:

```
// Defining interface for model instances
interface UserInstance extends Sequelize.Instance<UserInstance, UserAttribute> {
  ... database field here ...
}

// Wrapper class managing connection & model definitions
class Db {
  public User() { /* ... get user model ... */ }
}

// Actually retrieving the data, db is instance of Db class
let user: UserInstance = await db.User().findOne(findOptions);
```

Now at this point the client code is hard-wired to sequelize, and we can't unit test anything without a live database.

I was thinking of implementing the database operations as a series of functions that instead take a database "connection" as a parameter and the type you want is passed in as a generic parameter, something like:

```
let user: UserInstance = dbHelper.findOne<UserInstance>(findOptions, connection);
```

The implementation of `findOne` could then use the connection object to actually do the right thing. A mock connection could return hard coded test data, while the real one could actually make the sequelize call.

However, I'm a little stuck on how I would implement the findOne functionality in the sequelize connection object. Note that the generic type passed is `UserInstance`, not user. I don't want to pass in the result of a call to `db.User` because that does a ton of sequelize stuff and I'm hard coded back to sequelize again.

What I think I need to do this is something like this, which I know Typescript doesn't support:

```
interface ModelFinder<T> {
    getModel(db: DB): Sequelize.Model;
}

interface UserInstance implements ModelFinder<UserInstance> {
    getModel = (db) => db.User()
}
```

Then in my findOne code for sequelize I could do something like:

```
function findOne<TModel>(findOptions) {
  return getModel<TModel>(db).findOne(findOptions);
}
```

(Yeah, that's really messy). Basically, write a generic function that can look up information about a type at compile time.

I'm sure the C++ style traits aren't possible, since generic in Typescript use a type erasure model. I'd be willing to stick the information off to the side somewhere instead, but I don't know how to get a unique identifier for the type so I could look up the model at runtime.

If I had a class I could easily handle this by tacking on a property onto the constructor function, but I don't have a class, I have an interface.

Anyone got any ideas about how to do something like this? Or suggestions about how to do it some other way?